# More problem on van Aubel configuration associated with parallelogram and cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Problem 1:** Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram. Construct four squares on the sidelines $ABCD$. Let $NPMO$ be the [Thebault’s square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9bault's_theorem#Th%C3%A9bault%27s%20problem%20I). Show that:

1-Centers of four circles $(NAP)$, $(PBM)$, $(MCO)$, $(OCN)$ is rhombus.

2-Intersection of four circles $(NAP)$ and $(PBM)$, $(PBM)$ and $(MCO)$, $(MCO)$ and $(OCN)$, $(OCN)$  and $(NAP)$  form a square.
[image]

**Problem 2:** $ABCD$ be a parallelogram, construct for square on the sidelines of ABCD. Show that $OPMN$ be a rectangle.

[image]

**Problem 3:** Let $A, B, C, D$ lie on a circle with center $(O)$. Construct four squares on the sidelines $ABCD$. Let $PMNQ$ be the [van Aubel 's equidiagonal orthodiagonal quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Aubel's_theorem). Show that:

1-Six circles $(QAP)$, $(PBM)$, $(MCN)$, $(NDQ)$, $(PON)$, $(MOQ)$ are concurrent be a point.

2-Centers of four circles $(QAP)$, $(PBM)$, $(MCN)$, $(NDQ)$ lie on a circle.

3-Center of four circles $(QOP)$, $(POM)$, $(MON)$, $(NOQ)$ lie on a circle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for problem $2$.

(1) Line $GF$ and $JK$ are parallel.

*Proof.* $\triangle AFG \cong \triangle CJK$ and since $AF || CJ$ and $AG || CK$, the triangles are homothetic so $GF$ and $JK$. (An alternate argument would to be just apply desargues)

By symmetry, $HI || EL$ so it suffices to prove that

(2) $HI \perp GF$.

*Proof.* But this is trivial. Let $X, Y, Z, W$ be the centers of squares $ABFE, ADGH, DCIJ, CBKL$, respectively. From homothety wrt $A$, we find that $GF || XY$ and from homothety wrt $D$ we find that $HI || YZ$, so it suffices to prove that $XY \perp YZ$, but $XYZW$ form a Thebault's square so we are done.